# Varied response times on partial updates dependent on last activity

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces

I have noticed for some time now that the response time on partial updates is a lot longer when there has been a time lapse since the last server request. As an example:

I request a page and immediately click a commandButton with an associated Ajax listener and I can see that the event fires straight away.

I request the same page, wait say 30 seconds, and then click the same commandButton and the event can take maybe 5 seconds to fire ... even 10 seconds.

Can someone please explain why this is, and how I can fix it?

*JBoss 4.2.3 | MyFaces 2.1.9 | PrimeFaces 3.4.2*

Comment: Are you observing this in `<f:ajax>` or `<p:ajax>` or both? It'd be helpful for PrimeFaces/MyFaces guys if you mention the browser used (and try different ones) as well.

Comment: Apologies. Same behaviour in IE9 (64bit) & Firefox 16. I don't use <f:ajax> but just tried it to check it out, and the same happens. It also happens using actionListener on Primefaces components.

Comment: Okay. It's most likely how the container manages open HTTP connections. JBoss 4.2.3 is rather ancient. Do you see chance to tryout the same on JBoss 7 / Tomcat 7 / Glassfish 3, even if it's just to exclude JBoss 4.2.3 from being the suspect?

Comment: It is rather ancient. I would *love* to be using JBoss 7 etc instead but it is a big job to upgrade and we don't have the time at the moment :(. Interesting you think it may the container. Might have a look and see if there's a configuration setting I can tweak :)